# C# - Directory Structure from XML

Tags: c#, xml, subdirectory

Using C# I have an XML file containing a folders structure, the user selects the main project folder then the system begins checking the sub-folders in the main project folder based on the structure of the XML file. The folder structure is dynamic as the admin of the application can add/remove/modify a folder within the structure by changing the XML file.

How do I loop through the XML, I tried using XmlDocument to get the full directory pathbut I read about using XDocument for better result but my knowledge of XML is still basic.

The XML file structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<dir name="Site Documents">
  <dir name="External">
    <dir name="Mechanical">
      <dir name="01. Submittals">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="02. Drawings">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="03. MIR">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="04. IR">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
    </dir>
    <dir name="Electrical">
      <dir name="01. Submittals">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="02. Drawings">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="03. MIR">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="04. IR">
        <dir name="1. Sent">
        </dir>
        <dir name="2. Received" />
      </dir>
    </dir>
  </dir>
  <dir name="Internal">
    <dir name="01. PR">
      <dir name="1. MECH">
      </dir>
      <dir name="2. ELEC" />
    </dir>
    <dir name="02. PO">
    </dir>
    <dir name="03. SRF">
    </dir>
    <dir name="04. RMR" />
  </dir>
</dir>
```

**EDIT -- 1**

I tried using this test code to get the path of the node and sub-node

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\John_Doe\_data\directory_hirarchy.xml");
            XmlNodeList xmlFolderName = xDoc.SelectNodes("//dir");
            MessageBox.Show(xmlFolderName.Count.ToString());
            string finalText = "";
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < xmlFolderName.Count; ctr++)
            {
                string DocFolder = xmlFolderName[ctr].Attributes["name"].InnerText;
                finalText = finalText + DocFolder + "\r\n";
            }
            txtDisplay.Text = finalText; // Test text box for Output Result
        }
```

The output of the text box is:

`Site Documents
External
Mechanical
01. Submittals
1. Sent
2. Received
02. Drawings
1. Sent
2. Received
03. MIR
1. Sent
2. Received
04. IR
1. Sent
2. Received
Electrical
01. Submittals
1. Sent
2. Received
02. Drawings
1. Sent
2. Received
03. MIR
1. Sent
2. Received
04. IR
1. Sent
2. Received
Internal
01. PR
1. MECH
2. ELEC
02. PO
03. SRF
04. RMR`

Solved by Daisy Shipton

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var directories = doc.Descendants("dir");

        foreach (var dir in directories)
        {
            var parts = dir
                .AncestorsAndSelf() // All the ancestors of this element, and itself
                .Reverse()          // Reversed (so back into document order)
                .Select(e => e.Attribute("name").Value); // Select the name
            var path = string.Join("/", parts);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, XDocument makes things much simpler. You can loop over all the directory elements using `doc.Descendants("dir")`. You say you tried using `XmlDocument` - could you show that code and explain in what way it didn't work for you?

Comment: @DaisyShipton I have edited my post with the code, I simply tried to make a loop with the number of elements named "dir" and get its path then check it with `Directory.Exists` but this code don't return the full path only the name of the element

Comment: Depending on how big the file is, you could deserialise it into memory using XmlSerializer().  Use Xsd to create the backing objects or alternatively, use Paste Special from the Edit menu, then you have simple C# objects you can iterate through.

Comment: @Tima: Okay, so all you're looking for is code that builds up the full path based on the nesting?

Comment: Yes, exactly. the path of the node will be the path I am checking. I also don't mind using XDocument if it do the trick.

Comment: It is not need to edit the solution in your question. Your accept of the answer should be enough to communicate that.

Comment: @rene Fair enough Just wanted to share the knowledge to other that's all anyways thanks for illustrating that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options here:

- Use recursion, so you can keep track of "the path so far"
- Just look at all elements, but use their ancestors to build up the path

The first is probably simplest to understand, and yes, using LINQ to XML makes life simpler.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        PrintDirectories(doc, null);        
    }

    static void PrintDirectories(XContainer parent, string path)
    {
        foreach (XElement element in parent.Elements("dir"))
        {
            string dir = element.Attribute("name").Value;
            string fullPath = path == null ? dir : $"{path}/{dir}";
            Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
            PrintDirectories(element, fullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

The non-recursive approach is about the same size, but possibly harder to understand if you're not familiar with LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var directories = doc.Descendants("dir");

        foreach (var dir in directories)
        {
            var parts = dir
                .AncestorsAndSelf() // All the ancestors of this element, and itself
                .Reverse()          // Reversed (so back into document order)
                .Select(e => e.Attribute("name").Value); // Select the name
            var path = string.Join("/", parts);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I am trying your 1st method but I am stuck with this line `string fullPath = path == null ? dir : $"{path}/{dir}";` as I am using windows form application, sorry if this is not relevant to the subject.

Comment: @Tima: It should be fine, assuming you're using a C# 6 compiler or later. If you're using an earlier version of C#, you can just use `string fullPath = path == null ? dir : path + "/" + dir;`

Comment: Thanks, both methods yield path like that: `Site Documents/External/Mechanical/01. Submittals/1. Sent`